# How can I use an optional value with if statement?

Tags: ios, swift

I get "sinavid" from xml file and I want to use the value of "id" (one of the tag in xml..)

If the value of id=2, main view go to other view which storyboard id=2

but I can't use the value of sinavid because of optional value (I think)

P.S: Sorry for my English :(

```
sinavid = haberler.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).valueForKey("id") as! NSString as String 

if (sinavid! == "2"){

        row = "b"

        let viewcontroller = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(row)
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewcontroller!, animated: true)


    }

    else {

        let viewcontroller = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(row)
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewcontroller!, animated: true)


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if let sinaVID = sinavid, sinaVID == "2"  {
    row = "b"
    let viewcontroller = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(row)
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewcontroller!, animated: true)
} else {
    let viewcontroller = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(row)
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewcontroller!, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: In the 'else' part, 'row' is missing.

Comment: it still doesn't go to the other view which id = 2
i can write value of id(sinavid) to uilabel it is 2

Comment: but i cant use it with if statement

Comment: I though your question was just about how to write if statement for an optional value. so i write if let sinaVID = sinavid, sinaVID == "2" . everything else should be your logic .

Answer (score 1):

Your code would not show the same error with just removing `!`:

```
if (sinavid == "2"){
```

---

But this line may cause your app crash, with a very risky `as!` casting.

```
sinavid = haberler.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).valueForKey("id") as! NSString as String
```

If you are not 100% sure about its safety, you better use `as?` with Optional binding.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `?` instead of `!`.
With question mark you cast a value as optional value.

Answer (score 0):

First of all stop using `valueForKey:`, KVC is not needed at all in this case.

A suitable and easy way to check for a specific non-optional value is optional binding with the `where` clause

```
if let sinavid = haberler[indexPath.row]["id"] as? String where sinavid == "2" {
    row = "b"
    let viewcontroller = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(row)
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewcontroller!, animated: true)
}
else {
    let viewcontroller = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(row)
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewcontroller!, animated: true)
}
```